# Why is mysqli_connect() an "undefined function" on my PHP server?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using PHP Version 5.3.3 on a Linux server.  When I try to use mysql_connect() or mysqli_connect() to reach the database, I get an error saying:

**Fatal error:** Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

or

**Fatal error:** Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

You can see my testing page here: http://gorp.osg.ufl.edu/BOT3151/testing.php

You can see the phpinfo page here: http://gorp.osg.ufl.edu/phptest.php

The relevant configure commands are here:

`'--with-mysql=shared,/usr' 
'--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config' 
'--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config'`

It also says that these .ini files are being parsed:

`/etc/php.d/mysql.ini
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini`

The php.ini file also includes these lines:

`extension=mysql.so
extension=mysqli.so`

So what's going wrong here?  Is mySQL not properly installed on the server?  How can I fix this?

ADDENDUM: I should have explained that this is on a shared server that I don't administer.  I just have access to my folder on the server through SFTP.  But I do have a php.ini file and I have an extensions folder.  So is this something I can fix myself or do I need help from a server administrator?

Comment: 5.3.3 is from 2010. Is it possible to abandon that historical version and install something newer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "mysqli" extension is not loaded. You can NOT see the section in your phpinfo() file.

http://gorp.osg.ufl.edu/phptest.php

You should see something like this on that page:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7VdYIkRLxQWaDRLYVNLeU84am8

Just because you have uncommented the line `extension=mysqli.so` does not mean it will load. The file `mysqli.so` is possibly not in a folder where PHP is looking for it or does not exist at all.

Check "extension_dir" in your `php.ini` file. Then go and see if the file `mysqli.so` is actually there.

Have you restarted your web server?

Comment: I have a PHP.ini file and an extensions folder, but I don't know what to put in there.  Do I need to get the mysqli.so file?  Where do I get it?  I haven't tried restarting the server because (I assume) only an administrator can do that.  Or is there a way just to restart my own part of it?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't realise you have no access to the server. You have to ask somebody who does in that case and just tell them mysql is not properly installed. At the same time I would ask for an upgrade in php as well just as others suggested.

Comment: I haven't found the mysqli.so file, but that doesn't mean it isn't somewhere on the server.  Maybe the "extension_dir" line in my php.ini file is set to the wrong place.  Right now I have it pointed at an (empty) folder called "ext" inside the "cgi-bin" folder inside my site.  Should it go somewhere else?  One source I looked at said it should say something like extension_dir = "/usr/local/php5/lib/php/extensions/"  I found the "/usr/local/" file structure at the base of the server, but there's no folder in that called "php5."

Comment: It turned out that the problem was my php.ini file. Somehow, just having one in my own cgi-bin folder was preventing the mysql and mysqli extensions from loading.  Once I deleted the php.ini file, everything worked fine.

Comment: Voted down for having a link that no longer exists (the google docs link, not the questions link).  Please include all relevant details in the answer as external links expire / get moved (or the google docs files get deleted).

Answer (score 2):

Try to install PHP MySQL by:

```
apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Then your MySQL is easily set with your PHP and Apache setting. If your MySQL is installed already you can uninstall it first and then try to install PHP MySQL by the code above in a terminal.

It is the easiest way to do it without needing any settings.

Comment: Is that something I can do myself, or does it need to be done by the server administrator?  I only have a folder on a shared server.

Comment: Is the problem on your server? So the server doesn't have mysql! you need to check with them if the server is mysql support. if it is then you need to ask the server administrator to fix it as you only have a share host.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your PHP info page does not list a section displaying the MySQL configuration, it stands to reason that MySQL may not be installed on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue. There was some problem with the default values in php.ini file. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46833562/5088262) answer if your problem wasn't solved with the answer given above.