# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/ck/public_html/conn.php on line 6

Tags: php, mysqli

conn.php

```
<?php
$user_name="root";
$password="*****";
$database="user";
$server="localhost";
$link=mysqli_connect($server,$user_name,$password,$database);
if(!link)
{
    echo "not";
}
else
{
    echo "";
}
```

?>

When I visit on my website it show

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/ck/public_html/conn.php on line 6
```

How can I fix this problem ? Please Help

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757636/php-fatal-error-on-mysqli-connect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is mysqli\_connect() an "undefined function" on my PHP server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31148711/why-is-mysqli-connect-an-undefined-function-on-my-php-server)

Comment: Thanks Shafiqul Islam I sort out my problem