# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect(). Tried solution from other similar questions but no luck

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

Before marking duplicate please understand that I have tried all the solutions mentioned in other similar question.
I have hosted my website in amazon ec2.
I have done everything possible to make `mysqli_connect` work, still didn't find solution for it.

Have tried following in php.ini

1. comment out : `extension=msql.so` 
   `extension=php_mysqli.dll`
2. restarted apache2 server.

the code is as follows.

where i have defined those variables before using.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
?>
```

The error I am getting is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/connect.php:2

Please be supportive and help me..

Comment: Try the `new mysqli()` instead or PDO.

Comment: @mega6382 +1 for "or PDO"

Comment: @mega6382 Those functions are aliases, if one doesn't exist so won't the other.

Comment: php version is 7.0

Comment: you would probably need to post (all the) code you're using for this, and if you're using a class/methods etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am trying just basic connection right now. Have just created a db and trying to connect to it. So my code is just the one i have added(after editing just now)

Comment: @ishwarrimal Have you tried `PDO`?

Comment: No.. I haven't used it till now. Idk how that works. I will check and will let u know if i face some issue

Comment: @mega6382 tried with new mysqli and its working now. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @deceze Check the OP response. `new mysqli()` worked.

Comment: @mega6382 Then PHP is broken: http://www.php.net/mysqli_connect

Comment: I am sorry @mega6382 and deceze i had some other syntax error this time. So didnt get any error with respect to mysqli. But now after fixing it. Got error as 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/connect.php'

Comment: @deceze getting this error. 'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/connect.php'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the solution. 
There were three things I was doing wrong.

1. Since i am working in linux, uncommenting `msql.so` was required rather then uncommenting `mysqli.dll`.
2. Second, I was uncommenting in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`, but instead i was to make those changes in cli i.e `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`.
3. Third, the file named `msql.so` was not there in the directory ('lib/php/'), instead it was `mysqli.so`. Therefore changing the name from `msql.so` to `mysqli.so` in `php.ini` did the trick for me.

Hope this will help somebody someday.